# seemingly nontrivial question about covering maps and evenly covered open sets

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $p : E \to B$ be a covering map. And also assume that $B$ is path-connected and locally path-connected. Then, given y in $B$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $y_1$ in $B$ that is path-connected and evenly covered by $p$. Now the inverse image of $U$ by $p$ consists of slices $\{V_a\}$. Take a point $x$ in $E$ such that $p(x)=y$ and let $V'$ be the slice containing $x$.

Now the questions is, if $N$ is an arbitrary neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, then how to replace $U$ by a smaller neighborhood of $y$ such that the slice $V'$ containing $x$ can be included in the $N$? It seems very nontrivial to me...In the text I read, there is no detailed explanation about this. Could anyone give me some rigorous proof?

Comment: [Please read this to learn how to properly format your questions and answers.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117).

Comment: You probably meant $y$ instead of $y_1$. And what does it mean "such that the slice $V′$ containing $x$ can be included in the $N$"?

Comment: Hint: $V'$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, and $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$. Can you think of a way to replace $V'$ by a smaller neighborhood of $x$ that is included in $N$?

Comment: Another (duplicate?) question contains also an excerpt from the book: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966222/a-question-about-the-proof-of-general-lifting-theorem-in-munkres-topology-p-479